# Windows 2016 HyperV Edition rescan hardware change

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2016

I have some problem with Windows 2016 HyperV Edition. It is Core only, and no GUI. Problem is that the mainboard is broken, and I need to replace it. But after replacing it, Windows doesn't recognize anything. Onboard LAN dead, GPU is not recognized, and PCIe LAN is also dead. Even USB is not working. Network and internet is out of question. Keyboard is PS/2 only, no USB flash drive. So it must be something inside Windows Server itself. Therefore Devcon is also out of question.

How to perform hardware rescan? Any idea to revive this? Reinstall HyperV? Running an upgrade? Anything without reinstalling virtual machines will do.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any chance to copy to server the installation files? If so, you can try to install drivers manually - https://ortuno2k.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/installing-drivers-on-windows-server-core/
Also, this one might be helpful - https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26163877/Server-2008-Script-to-detect-new-hardware.html

Comment: That pnputil should prove useful. The drivers should be there already, since I am using the same type and brand. It's just Windows 2016 won't detect the new mainboard.
I don't have installation files, so I will have to boot to USB and perform reinstall. If I boot into USB, and perform reinstall, will my VM still there? Because it seems HyperV uses different kind of VM store than VMWare, and I don't seem able to run a disconnected VHDX properly without exporting it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up by reformatted OS partition, and reinstalling Operating System, and import virtual machine, then choose in-place import.